# Why is my Brother MFC-8440 not showing in CUPS Rasberry Pi 3B

Tags: raspberry-pi, cups

I have a RasPi 3B and I need to put the **Brother MFC-8440** on the network so everyone can access it.

But, unlike my Samsung and HP printers, this one does not show in CUPS, in LSUSB it shows

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04f9:015f Brother Industries, Ltd MFC-8440
```

so I don't understand what the problem could be.

I'm really new to the RasPi thing so please excuse any mistakes I might have made.

Comment: you most definitely would need drivers installed. See: https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_rppx2.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on as well as https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=116509

Comment: Thank you for the comment but how would i download and extract the file, im using putty to connect to the pi?

Comment: Postscript-Brother → https://www.openprinting.org/driver/Postscript-Brother . ... Files, e.g. package.deb : $ wget https://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/openprinting-ppds-postscript-brother_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb

Comment: @KnudLarsen
The "How to install" links does not work so i'm still stuck.
I'm really noob to the world of Pi, its my first day working on one

Comment: Install a downloaded package : `$ sudo gdebi openprinting-ppds-postscript-brother_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb` .... or if no 'gdebi' available : `$ sudo dpkg -i openprinting-ppds-postscript-brother_20130226-1lsb3.2_all.deb
`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks, your suggestion solved my problem.